# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to get an index.html to use this script:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

To upload an mp3-file by connect to this (which is called upload.php):

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3") //File type
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 21000000)  //20MB File Size
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "";//another echo to display after upload is complete

    if (file_exists("mp3/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "mp3/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
//Below shows the link for the mp3
      echo "http://www.Domain here". "mp3/" . $_FILES //Only change domain here leave directory

["file"]["name"] ."";
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Extension not allowed"; //Error message here if it's to big or wrong extension
  }
?>
```

But I always wind up getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/xxxx/test/upload.php on line 5
```

I've been trying to find the issue myself by adding/removing }'s after looking through topics here on Stack Overflow, but failed. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a closing `)`

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3") //File type
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 21000000))  //20MB File Size
  {
```

Kind of obvious really.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 21000000)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        } else {
            echo ""; //another echo to display after upload is complete

            if (file_exists("mp3/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "mp3/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                //Below shows the link for the mp3
                echo "http://www.Domain here" . "mp3/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . ""; //Only change domain here leave directory

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Extension not allowed"; //Error message here if it's to big or wrong extension
    }
?>
```